# Show unique values only when using CTE - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
with GTS_cte AS
    (SELECT distinct [BusinessTermID], GTS_T = 
    STUFF                   ((SELECT ', ' + dbo.TblField.GTS_table
                             FROM      dbo.TblField
                             WHERE   [BusinessTermID] = Y.[BusinessTermID] AND dbo.TblField.GTS_table <> '' FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
     FROM      dbo.Tblfield AS Y
     GROUP BY [BusinessTermID])

    ,
  syn_cte as (
SELECT [BusinessTermID], syns = STUFF
                      ((SELECT ', ' + dbo.TblBusinessSynonym.Synonym
                        FROM      dbo.TblBusinessSynonym
                        WHERE   [BusinessTermID] = x.[BusinessTermID] AND dbo.TblBusinessSynonym.Synonym <> '' FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM     dbo.TblBusinessSynonym AS x
GROUP BY [BusinessTermID])


select syn_cte.BusinessTermID, syn_cte.syns, GTS_cte.GTS_T 
from  syn_cte  join 
  GTS_cte on GTS_cte.BusinessTermID = syn_cte.BusinessTermID
```

It is concatenating the fields correctly and linking them but it is now creating duplicates. My result set looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to show only Unique values in GTS_T?

Thank you

Comment: Just use `select distinct` as you do in the first subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`DISTINCT`** inside your **`Sub-Query`**.

Try this:

```
;with GTS_cte AS
    (SELECT [BusinessTermID], GTS_T = 
    STUFF                   ((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + dbo.TblField.GTS_table
                             FROM      dbo.TblField
                             WHERE   [BusinessTermID] = Y.[BusinessTermID] AND dbo.TblField.GTS_table <> '' FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
     FROM      dbo.Tblfield AS Y
     GROUP BY [BusinessTermID])

    ,
  syn_cte as (
SELECT [BusinessTermID], syns = STUFF
                      ((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + dbo.TblBusinessSynonym.Synonym
                        FROM      dbo.TblBusinessSynonym
                        WHERE   [BusinessTermID] = x.[BusinessTermID] AND dbo.TblBusinessSynonym.Synonym <> '' FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM     dbo.TblBusinessSynonym AS x
GROUP BY [BusinessTermID])


select syn_cte.BusinessTermID, syn_cte.syns, GTS_cte.GTS_T 
from  syn_cte  join 
  GTS_cte on GTS_cte.BusinessTermID = syn_cte.BusinessTermID
```